# Adding an element to a specific location in a list

Tags: python, list, append

```
#Say I have the lists
l1 = [2,3,6,7,9]
l2 = [11,14,16,20,21]

# and a random number, say 8
x = 8

# And I want to change l1 so that if there is any number larger than
# 8 it will be deleted, then 8 will be inserted into the end of l1
#  the output would look like this: [2,3,6,7,8]

# And I want to change l2 so that if there is any number smaller than
# 8 it will be deleted, then 8 will be inserted into the beginning of l2
#  the output would look like this: [8,11,14,16,20,21]
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, and would sincerely appreciate some help.  Thanks!

Comment: I know I should use an if statement to delete the elements, and I can use the append function to place the 8 in the list.  But, I'm not sure if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
l1 = [i for i in l1 if i <= 8]
l1 = l1 + [8]
```

(or `l1.append(8)`)

and:

```
l2 = [i for i in l2 if i >= 8]
l2 = [8] + l2
```

(or `l2.insert(0, 8)` which is presumably faster)

Comment: Thank you!  My method had way to many lines of code.  I know I can use append to put 8 in the end f the list, but how would I put something in front?

Comment: @PiccolMan it's in my answer :)

Comment: You don't actually have to create new lists, it is possible to delete list items with `del`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
l1 = [i for i in l1 if i <= x]

l1.append(x)

l2 = [i for i in l2 if i >= x]

l2.insert(0, x)
```

Comment: Ended up posting anyway? ;)

Comment: @Idos Yes, but I use the variable rather than a constant :)